# Dedekind Domains Proof Question

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $R$ is a Dedekind domain, $I$ an ideal in  $R$ and $a,b\in R$, then the congruence $ax =b\pmod I$ has a solution $x \in R$ iff the element $b$ lies in the ideal $I + aR$.

I wonder why don't use the condition Dedekind domain in the proof.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's true for every ring, as
$$\exists x:ax\equiv b\pmod I \iff \exists x:b-ax\in I \iff b\in I+aR\,.$$